# whatsapp account on both ubuntu and windows at a time

Tags: whatsapp

I have a dual boot for Windows and Ubuntu. In Windows I use bluestacks and in Ubuntu I use AndroVM. The problem is first I had installed whatsapp in bluestacks and created an account. Another time when I logged in to Ubuntu, I installed whatsapp on AndroVM too and created an account. Now I can't use whatsapp from bluestacks because, it says something like 'same no. can't be used on two devices'.

How to have whatsapp on both bluestacks and AndroVM at a time?

Comment: You answered your own question: the same number can't be used on two devices

Comment: One blog post claims you can achieve this if both devices (virtual machines in your case) have the same MAC address. If you're rooted, try this: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=20172118&postcount=1

Comment: That's currently possible with Telegram, F.Messenger and Whatsapp Business API, but not with normal Whatsapp version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can not run two whatsapp account in same machine. Even if its your dual sim smartphone or your computer, only one whatsapp account can be run from one number from one machine. Whatsapp server detects the mac address of your system and disconnect the previous login session.

Source

I have try to achieve it many time on my PC (Linux and win) and Android smartphone. Failed !

Answer (score 1):

### Use Whatsapp Business API

Having multiple devices with Whatsapp opened (besides the mobile device) is now possible with the new Whatsapp Business API, but as the name suggests, is focused on Business users.